# The position rule of "sich" (Reflexivepronomen)?

Tags: reflexive

So yesterday, when we are learning about the Reflexivepronomen with Reflexiveverben and the positioning, I am clear with this example.

> Ich habe mich **erholt**.
>
> Hast du **dich** gut **erholt**? (0)

But notice the following Reflexivepronomen position (sich come after the verb)

> Verabredet **sich** Klaus mit seinen Freunden? (1)

but not like this:

> Verabredet Klaus **sich** mit seinen Freunden? (2)

*My question is which one of (1) (2) is correct? and why?*

One more example is:

> Jan hat **sich** die ganze Zeit mit anderen Kollegin unterhalten. Da hat **sich** eine Kundin beschwert.

*why this one is placed after the connector (da)*

*My question is which one of (1) (2) is correct? and why?*
*Why does it not the same position with (0)?*

Comment: I have my question edited. Please help! @infinitezero

Comment: Both are correct. Since *da* is the first word in the second example, I don't understand the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Ich **habe** mich **erholt**.*

A verb-second clause (V2 clause). The *mich* is in mid-field position (where else?).

> ***Hast** du dich gut **erholt**?*

A verb-first clause (V1 clause). So we need to arrange the three elements in the mid-field, *du*, *dich*, and *gut*. You have two complements, *du* and *dich*. Rule: With pronominal complements, the subject complement comes before any accusative/dative/genitive complement(s), hence *du dich*, not *dich du*. (Broader *tendency*: "active" complements come before "less active" complements.) "Quality supplements" (in the form of adverbs, adjectives, participles, etc) that modify the verbal expression usually come last within the mid-field.

> ***Verabredet** sich Klaus mit seinen Freunden?*

Another V1 clause. We need to arrange *sich*, *Klaus*, and *mit seinen Freunden*. In arranging *sich* and *Klaus* and I'm afraid there are no clear rules as to their position. Generally speaking: (1) Pronouns (including *sich*, at least for purposes of this analysis) tend to come before nouns. (2) Exceptionally, a nominal subject can take the position of a pronominal subject. If you think about that, it's still not clear whether the *sich* or the *Klaus* come first. Both is possible. There is however a tendency to place the *sich* ahead of the antecedent. It is not so easy to explain that. Some linguists once suggested as part of a broader theory that this has something to do with the "lightweightness" of *sich* in such cases (it is simply required as part of a reflexive verb and, among other things, usually does not bear the sentence accent), basically suggesting that it does not play in the same "league" as the rest of the mid-field.

> *Jan hat sich die ganze Zeit mit anderen Kollegin unterhalten. Da **hat** sich eine Kundin **beschwert**.*

Another V2 clause. (By the way, since you call *da* a "connector": *Da* can be a connector *(Ich mag Max, da [= because] er nett ist.)* However, here it's simply an adverb, which could be translated as "at one point". In this predominantly deictic use, it almost always appears in the pre-field of V2 clauses, as in this case.) In the mid-field, we need to arrange *sich* and *eine Kundin*. The analysis is the same as above.